# how to debug error of bad integer though the input is ok

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a fortran code, which I led it read integer from command. I define on code these input parameters are integers and also I gave integers on command like this:
./density -o data -s 1 -k 8 -b 20
But it showed an error that
Fortran runtime error: Bad integer for item 1 in list input.
What 's wrong with that code? Please help me!

```
integer s,b,k
if(option == "-o") then
    read(value,*) outputfile
else if(option == "-s") then
    read(value,*) s
else if(option == "-k") then
    read(value,*) k
else if(option == "-b") then
    read(value,*) b
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always present a minimal working program, not just a snippet of a source code. In youre code it is not clear how the command line arguments are stored into 'option' and 'value'. A working example could be:

```
program cmd_read
!
implicit none
!
integer, parameter :: MAXARG=8                   ! There are four pairs of arguments
character(len=1024), dimension(MAXARG)   :: args
character(len=2)   , dimension(MAXARG/2) :: options = (/'-o', '-s' , '-k', '-b' /)
character(len=1024)                      :: outputfile = ' '
integer :: iarg      ! number of arguments
integer :: i         ! dummy loop index
integer :: ios       ! io error status
integer :: s=0, k=0, b==   ! command line integer values, provide default values
!
args = ' '           ! ensure that they are blank
iarg = COMMAND_ARGUMENT_COUNT()   ! Get number of arguments
if(iarg >  0) then   ! Always keep in mind that there might be no arguments
   do i = 1, iarg
      call GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT (i, args(i) )
   enddo
endif
!
do i= 1, iarg, 2      ! argument names are odd arguments
!                     ! Arguments might be in different sequence
   if(args(i)==options(1)) then      ! An alternative is the "CASE" construct
      outputfile = args(i+1)
   elseif(args(i)==options(2)) then
      read(args(i+1),*, iostat=ios) s
      if(ios/=0) then
         write(*,*) ' Error on -s'
      endif
   elseif(args(i)==options(3)) then
      read(args(i+1),*) k
   elseif(args(i)==options(4)) then
      read(args(i+1),*) b
   endif
enddo
write(*,'(a, i4, i4, i4)') outputfile(1:len_trim(outputfile)), s, k, b
!
end program cmd_read
```

This program does not yet check if the command line arguments were present, and are in a sensible numerical range. The I/O error check on '-s' is just a quick and dirty example to catch things like -s 1.8 or -s text